# Older style door trim

Tags: trim, door-frame

I am doing renovations on the inside of my really old house, and am looking to update my interior doors. I have the old style door trim and doors (skeleton key door locks), and the really old door trim, as shown in this picture: (Stock image, not mine)

[image: this style trim]

I am putting newer 6 slab prehung hollow cores in their place, and not really a fan of the older style trim. Since I can't just put 3/4" trim up now (since the baseboards would also need pulled up and replaced), do they sell trim kits that I can replace the old ones with that will match the width and height? Once I remove the top piece at least, I know there's a substantial amount of space that needs to be filled in. I'm sure I could probably find (or make my own) vertical pieces, it's more the height of the horizontal header piece that I am worried about.

If they don't make anything, since I don't want to deal with replacing the plaster to allow for smaller trim, I guess I will have to resort to using the older style trim :(

I'm looking for a kit like this or something, but that will allow me to match the height of the vertical piece of trim I currently have:

[image: This is the style i'd like to use]

Comment: Are you planning on staying in the house a very long time?  I ask because I'm actually putting the type of moulding that you currently have in my house because I love the way it looks.  My point is that other people will really like the old moulding, and it's going to be a big expense in time and money to change it.  Consider if its really worth it.

Comment: Yes, I do plan on staying there for a long time. Most of the molding that is up there now is chewed up, dinged, damaged or otherwise incomplete. The house is nearly 100 years old, and a lot of the trim has started to splinter or seperate and warp.

Comment: Can't really judge it if you're going to use stock images.  Those stock images you are using are the low end of the classic looking trim, and are available at any store for a couple of bucks.  All they are is just *not* the usual modernist ticky-tacky that's intentionally characterless.

Comment: Which image are you referring to? Both images are from homes, just not mine. The top image looks exactly like my trim. The bottom trim is fluted but doesn't look wide enough across the header.

Answer (score 3):

You could buy 1x5 MDF, its about $2 per foot at the big box store.  It's a similar material as a hollow 6 panel modern door, and is about the same width as the trim in your stock photo.  Then you can replace your classic turn of the century solid old growth timber doors and trim with modern manufactured products.  Another option is repair and paint, give the hinges some oil, and be proud of your home's original style that can no longer be bought!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately, I do not like the old clunkyness and weight of the old doors, nor do I like the look of the old lock plates that came on them. 90% of all of my doors that are on now either can't close all the way because the hinges and screws have come loose shifting the door, or the latches themselves are so old and painted over that they no longer function to hold the door in place. Plus, I don't like the look of old style decor. It makes the house look extremely old and outdated, and I've not seen anybody who has been able to make it look any different.